# Attaching pdf in mail magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm having a custom module for bulk purchase of products. Also, the customers can request for separate quote for the products they are purchasing. After that the admin will create the quote based on request. The quote details will be sent as mail. I want to attach a pdf with the same quote details in the mail. So how can I attain the same. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

1) Override the app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php file in your module

2) Add one protected variable `$pdftemplate`

3) Edit the `send()` function

4) at line around **70** put the following code:

```
if ($this->pdftemplate)
      $pdftemplate = $this->variable;
else
      $pdftemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

5) At the end of the class put:

```
public function addAttachment(Zend_Pdf $pdf, $filename){
    $file = $pdf->render();
    $this->pdftemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    $attachment = $this->pdftemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($file);
    $attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
    $attachment->filename = $filename;
}
```

6) Override app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php

7) Override the function sendEmail()

after

```
$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
```

put

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($this));
$mailer->addAttachment($pdf,'invoice.pdf');
```